# Linear Time Invariant System Causality

Tags: signal-processing

If I have an LTI system defined by the recursive difference equation:

$$y[n] = -\sum_{k=1}^{N} a_k y[n-k] + \sum_{k=0}^{M} b_k x[n-k]$$,

why can't I say the system is causal? The output at each time n depend on the past output values and the current and past input values.

Watch 9:28-9:56 and 10:25-11:50 of [this MIT video](http://youtu.be/1uoUUJBsSlU)  OR just watch 11:40-11:50 if you are short on time.

Comment: This system is causal. Who says it isn't?

Comment: Watch 9:28-9:56 and 10:25-11:50 of this MIT video: https://youtu.be/1uoUUJBsSlU   OR just watch 11:40-11:50 if you are short on time.

Comment: might be that I'm tired, because I'd tend to believe what I see when it's told by a professor of the discipline at MIT, but I really don't follow his. First, set \$x[n]= 0\$. Then, the L in LTI demands that \$y[n] = 0\$. From that follows that \$y[l]\$ for \$l<0\$ = 0. Setting \$x[n]=\delta[x]\$ would make \$y[n]\$ the impulse response, \$y[n]=h[n]\$, by definition. Now, because we've noticed the system can't generate any output prior to \$n=0\$ by the constraint found in the \$x[n]=0\$ case, this implies causality.

Comment: @MarcusMüller only if M and N are \$\le\$n.

Comment: That video was weird, at 9:28 he asks if LTI means that it is casual (which it doesn't), then at 11:40 he says that the equation isn't casual because "it wasn't casual before" (I assume he means 9:28). But he didn't say it was not casual then. - To me, he's describing a casual system at 11:40, definitely the way he says it.

Answer (score 1):

The only possible way that I can conceive of that system being non-causal is if y[n] is not the output of the system.

As long as the forward time dependency is finite, it is always possible to add delay to the system to write it as a causal recurrence form.

That is, just multiplying the z-transform by \$z^{-N}\$ would yield a causal system.

But if y[n] is the output, it is causal.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the MIT lecture that originated this question,
https://youtu.be/1uoUUJBsSlU

Though he says that there are many reasons, the main thing that he's saying is "there's the whole issue of initial conditions ... so this equation is a constraint between the input and output, it's not a mapping from the input to the output."

The actual system output is dependent on its initial condition. Typically in practical signals you'd pre-load it with zeros or a run of something reasonable and just run it for a while to stabilize, but from a purely mathematical standpoint, it's dependent on the input x[n], past values of y[n], *and something else* to fully determine the output.

Answer (score -1):

Both \$\small M\le n\$ and \$N\small \le n\$ will make it causal. Non-causal otherwise.

Comment: That is a notational given. By notation 1 <= n <= N and 0 <= m <= M. For all n and m.

Comment: If M and N depend on n, then how is it time-invariant?